# Last new line disappears (gedit)

Tags: python, gedit

The last line disappears in files `in0` and `output0` if I open it in gedit and I'm not sure why?

Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2

```
from math import ceil, floor, log
from random import randint, choice

def in2text(table):
        out=''
        out+=str(len(table))+'\n'
        for t in table:
                out+=(str(t[0])+' '+str(t[1])+'\n')
        return out

def out2text(table):
        out=''
        for t in table:
                out+=(str(t)+'\n')
        return out

nr_inst=1000
max_n=1000000
in0=[randint(1, max_n) for e in range(1,nr_inst+1)]
input0=[[i,i] for i in in0]
output0=[5 for n,x in input0]

fin=open("in0","w")
fout=open("out0","w")
fin.write(in2text(input0))
fout.write(out2text(output0))
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Write function? If I print `in2text(input0)`, then I can see the last new line (enter, '\n').

I get (in out0):

```
5
5
5
...
5
5
```

without the last new line (the empty new line). I want:

```
5
5
5
...
5
5
<new line>
```

Why gedit do not show this line? Bug?

Comment: To khelwood: It is only an example. In the real program I have a function instead of 5. But why there is no '\n' at the end :(

Comment: @ZYX How do you know there is no `\n` at the end? Perhaps your file viewer doesn't display the last empty line?

Comment: Just ran it myself to triple check myself. This definitely prints the final newline into the file. My guess is whatever you're using to view it either strips it or hides it.

Comment: To  Pluckerpluck: Do you have the last empty line? Or the program gives only 5 and then nothing?

Comment: Yes. Opening it in vscode. I see the new line, line 1001 is blank.

Comment: Ok I opened it in gedit. Yes it true in gedit the last new line disappears. Thank you. This editor used to be so good.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1621732

Comment: It appears to be a bug in gedit. They know about it. Either use another text editor or don't worry about it.

Comment: Could you give a visible  answer to this question? I will approve it.

Answer (score 2):

The code itself runs correctly, it is instead how you view the file afterwards that's the issue. Specifically this appears to be a bug that exists within gedit.

[bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1621732](http://%20bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1621732)

Confirmed 2018-11-06